# Composer always rewriting same packages into cache

Tags: composer-php

While trying to optimise a composer flow I run into this issue.
Every time I run composer update -vvv I can see that there is a set of 10 modules that always gets rewritten into cache.
Composer version is 1.8.6

```
[15.1MiB/4.06s] Downloading https://repo.packagist.com/ourcompany/packages.json
[175.4MiB/21.64s] Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.com-ourcompany/packages.json into cache
[155.8MiB/21.68s] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
[156.0MiB/21.71s] Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.com-ourcompany/provider-myvendor$module-mymodule2-products.json from cache
[156.0MiB/21.71s] Downloading https://repo.packagist.com/ourcompany/p/myvendor/module-mymodule2-products.json
[156.0MiB/23.13s] Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.com-ourcompany/provider-myvendor$module-mymodule2-products.json into cache
................
................
[915.2MiB/46.60s] Resolving dependencies through SAT
```

The set of these packages is always the same, composer cache size is 2048MiB and increasing it didn't help.

Thanks for help.